# Converting date format from 04/08/13 to 2013-04-08 in ruby

Tags: ruby, date

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p429 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
1.9.3-p429 :002 > Date.strptime('04/08/13' , '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 => "0013-04-08"
```

For some reason, for the year, instead of **2013** it's showing **0013** ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have format with small mistake, it should be **`%m/%d/%y`**

```
Date.strptime('04/08/13', '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') => "2013-04-08"
```